# ExtJS: Ext.data.DataReader: #realize was called with invalid remote-data

Tags: extjs

I'm receiving a "Ext.data.DataReader: #realize was called with invalid remote-data" error when I create a new record via a POST request.  Although similar to the discussion [at this SO conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389135/extjs-throws-exception-realize-was-called-with-invalid-remote-data-on-successfu), my situation is slightly different:

My server returns the pk of the new record and additional information that is to be associated with the new record in the grid.  My server returns the following:

```
{'success':true,'message':'Created Quote','data': [{'id':'610'}, {'quoteNumber':'1'}]}
```

Where id is the PK for the record in the mysql database.  quoteNumber is a db generated value that needs to be added to the created record.

Other relevant bits:

```
var quoteRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([{name:'id', type:'int'},{name:'quoteNumber', type:'int'},{name:'slideID'}, {name:'speaker'},{name:'quote'}, {name:'metadataID'}, {name:'priorityID'}]);

var quoteWriter = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({ writeAllFields:false, encode:true });

var quoteReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({id:'id', root:'data',totalProperty: 'totalitems', successProperty: 'success',messageProperty: 'message',idProperty:'id'}, quoteRecord);
```

I'm stumped.  Anyone??

thanks

tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Responding with an answer instead of a comment for code formatting...]*

Some indented formatting will make the difference clear.  This (correct) form returns a single object with two properties:

```
{
    'success':true,
    'message':'Created Quote',
    'data': [{
        'id':'610',
        'quoteNumber':'1'
    }]
}
```

Your original format returned two separate objects with mismatched properties that cannot be resolved into columns:

```
{
    'success':true,
    'message':'Created Quote',
    'data': [{
        'id':'610'
    },{
        'quoteNumber':'1'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the response from the server should look like this:

```
{'success':true,'message':'Created Quote','data': [{'id':'610','quoteNumber':'1'}]}
```

A subtle difference, not one that I'm certain I understand.